# How can I enable Data Profiling tab in Airflow for Admin account?

Tags: airflow

I have created an Admin account in airflow. set rbac=True in airflow.cfg. After login in can see the **Data Profiling** Tab is not there, instead of it **Security** tab comes in picture.

I want the **Ad Hoq Query** for admin account. Is it possible to do so.

Version: 1.10.10

Answer (score 2):

Data Profiling Tab has been removed from RBAC UI due to security reasons.

From https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/57c8c05839f66ed2909b1bee8ff6976432db82aa/UPDATING.md#breaking-changes:

> Due to security concerns, the new WebServer (RBAC UI) will no longer support the features in the Data Profiling menu of old UI, including Ad Hoc Query, Charts, and Known Events.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have seen the link you share. just curious about whether we can able to tweak in code and make it enable. not sure how.

Comment: No, it is not a flag for RBAC UI as we have completed removed that functionality.